# Repository registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, autofac

```
        builder.RegisterType<DataContext>().As<DbContext>();

        builder.RegisterType<AnnoucementRepository>().As<IAnnouncementRepository>().WithParameter("DataContext", new DataContext()).InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<LanguageRepository>()
               .As<ILanguageRepository>()
               .WithParameter("DataContext", new DataContext())
               .InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

I have the above that, I want to find something better such that, I dont have to repeat `"DataContext", new DataContext()` for every repository i have.

How can i register Data context and inject to repositories? once per http request.

Comment: In theory this should work: `builder.RegisterType<DataContext>().InstancePerHttpRequest(); builder.RegisterType<AnnoucementRepository>().As<IAnnouncementRepository>().InstancePerHttpRequest();builder.RegisterType<LanguageRepository>()
               .As<ILanguageRepository>()
               .InstancePerHttpRequest()`

Comment: cannot resolve parameter 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext context' of constructor 'Void .ctor(System.Data.Entity.DbContext)'.

Comment: ok that actually worked. you wanna answer the question i ll mark it . thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are registering your `DataContext` as self using the `InstancePerHttpRequest` scope then Autofac will create one `DataContext` instance per request for you. Autofac will also inject it into your repositories without explicitly specifying as the parameter:

```
builder.RegisterType<DataContext>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

builder.RegisterType<AnnoucementRepository>()
       .As<IAnnouncementRepository>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder.RegisterType<LanguageRepository>()
       .As<ILanguageRepository>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

Side note: Actually in your original registration code you have created two separate `DataContext` instances which were not shared between your repositories.

Comment: related to your side note, is it better to share db context or not?

Comment: it depends on what you are doing in your repositories. But generally having one `DbContext` per one request and share it during that one request is a common practice.